# Chaos engineering experiment

Tags: chaos

Is it possible to have multiple iteration of single action in an experiment?

Say I want to run terminate-db-pod several times after each 600 sec.

```html
{
    "name": "all-our-microservices-should-be-healthy",
    "type": "probe",
    "tolerance": "true",
    "provider": {
        "type": "python",
        "module": "chaosk8s.probes",
        "func": "microservice_available_and_healthy",
        "arguments": {
            "name": "myapp",
            "ns": "myns"
        }
    }
},
{
    "type": "action",
    "name": "terminate-db-pod",
    "provider": {
        "type": "python",
        "module": "chaosk8s.pod.actions",
        "func": "terminate_pods",
        "arguments": {
            "label_selector": "app=my-app",
            "name_pattern": "my-app-[0-9]$",
            "rand": true,
            "ns": "default"
        }
    },
    "pauses": {
        "after": 5
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ref`

```
 { 
  ref: terminate-db-pod,
  type: action 
  }
```